# Text clustering takes too much time

Tags: r, text, cluster-analysis

I use TF-IDF and k-means clustering for text clustering in my MacBook pro. My data has 1400 observations and I want to have 140 clusters. The TF-IDF matrix has 101611692 elements (780.9 Mb). It tooks me 2 days already but the k-means clustering step hasn't finished yet. Is this too computationally expensive for a laptop and is there any faster method? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you trim the matrix?

Comment: Have you removed stop words? 100,000,000 is a lot of "elements". I assume you mean cells, which means you have about 70,000 words. Have you tried stemming? That should reduce some complexity. Beyond that you can also try reducing sparsity by dropping infrequent words, although you should be careful when doing that because you might lose information relevant to your TFIDFs. You might also want to take a look at `cluster::pam`, which allows some optimization via the `pamonce` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-Means is probably the simplest of all clustering algos.  It's complexity and processing time goes up linearly as the number of data points increases and the number of dimensions increases.  So it becomes virtually infeasible to run this methodology in high dimensional spaces with many data points.  Remove the stop words and try it on a much smaller sample, like 10% of what you are doing now.  Make sure it runs and does what you want, or you will burn through 2 days, and you will end up where you are now, wondering what happened, as nothing is getting done.